# Foundation 5 div styling

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation, styling

I am using Foundation 5 to create a website. Here's the main idea: I have a dark-grey background for the body, and I'd like to have 2 type of "posts" - A featured one with a red background, and a normal one with a white background. Here's what I have for the "post" div. I would like to have two distinct divs with the same small-9 small-centered columns properties.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="small-9 small-centered columns">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Perferendis pariatur laudantium unde quidem? In, id, voluptatum cumque quos quibusdam fugiat quas nihil odit porro reprehenderit delectus vero praesentium quidem autem!Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Odit commodi vel quibusdam non incidunt error doloribus. Eius, architecto, reiciendis omnis facilis minima autem amet fuga? Voluptatum architecto vel numquam id.
  </div>
</div>
```

How should I proceed in my style.css file to create two divs like that? I mean, when I started to write my css without using Foundation I just had a .post div and a .featured_post with borders, backgrounds and so on. I'm now trying to transition to Foundation, and I'm stuck. Any ideas would be appreciated. I guess my question is: should I style small-9 small-centered columns in my custom stylesheet or what?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The best practise way of using foundation is to use its mixins with your own CSS classes so that you markup remains as semantic as possible.

So keep your existing styles and add something like the following:

```
@media #{$small-up} {
  .posts {
    @include grid-row($behavior: nest);
    .post,
    .featured_post {
      @include grid-column($columns:9, $center:true);
    }
  }
}
```

The documentation is pretty decent: http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/grid.html